# RXJS: SwitchMap converts string into single characters unexpectedly

Tags: typescript, rxjs, observable

I am playing around with RXJS for TypeScript and stumbled upon an issue that I cannot explain myself. I have an `observable` that emits multiple strings. I then want to apply `switchMap` to it which is supposed to prepend "a" to each of those strings:

```
var o = Observable.create((observer) => {
    observer.next("hi")
    observer.next("bla")
})

o.switchMap(str => "a" + str).subscribe(str => console.log(str))
```

My expected output:

```
ahi
abla
```

Actual output:

```
a
h
i
a
b
l
a
```

So somewhere between switchMap and subscribe, the string gets broken down into characters apparently.

Can someone explain why this happens?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I guess you meant to use `map` instead of `switchMap`.

`switchMap` actually expects an [`ObservableInput`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/MiscJSDoc.js~ObservableInputDoc.html) as return-value, which in your case is a string, which in turn is treated as an array and therefore split up into single elements.

To have your expected result with `switchMap` you could do:

```
o.switchMap(str => Observable.of("a" + str))
    .subscribe(str => console.log(str));
```

But better use:

```
o.map(str => "a" + str)
    .subscribe(str => console.log(str))
```

New syntax with pipe:

```
o.pipe(
    map(str => "a" + str)
).subscribe(str => console.log(str))
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need `map` instead of `switchMap`.

The function passed to `switchMap` expects to return an observable or promise. `"a" + str` is not.